# SQL query for combining data from two sources in specified logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables in my SQL server setup.
Two of the tables are given below:

```
Product  Substitute  
  XXX       ABC      
  YYY       XYZ
```

Table two is similar to table one but lists alternates.

```
Product   Alternate  
 XXX       OPPP     
 YYY       FTTT
```

And I have a master table with the quantities of all the products (replacements and alternates included):

```
Product   Quantity
  XXX       52
  YYY       84
  ABC       180
  XYZ       220
 OPPP       590
 FTTT       760
```

Now I need an SQL query to list the total parts available for each main part number. For example, the output query should look like:

```
Product    Quantity     
  XXX        822
  YYY       1064
```

That is the total amount of XXX = total of XXX + total of ABC + total of OPPP.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Hello Dan, Tab. Yes I agree, there is no evidence of any research in my question. But I am still coming to grips with joins in SQL. And Julien's answer was very clear and also works well for my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first get all the data you need (inner query with union all).

Then you group the whole set of data by Product.

```
Select Product, Sum(Quantity)
From (
    Select Product, Quantity From master
    Union All
    Select a.Product, m.Quantity From master as m
    Inner join alternates as a on A.alternate = m.product
    Union All
    Select s.Product, m.Quantity From master as m
    Inner join Substitute as s on s.Substitute = m.product
) as p
Group By Product
```

Comment: Thank you Julien. Your answer was both lucid, clear and works amazingly well for my use case.